# Json Argonaut Too Big For Case Class

Tags: json, codec, case-class, hlist, argonaut

There's an API I have no influence on that has a JSON result object with a member that has 23 fields.  The paradigm of case classes doesn't work, because there's a limit of 22.  I've seen Slick and other libraries use HLists to resolve this.  Is there a way to do this in Argonaut?  If so, please give me sample piece of code to leverage. Thank you!

```
object BusinessResults{
    implicit def BusinessResultsCodecJson: CodecJson[BusinessResults] =
      casecodec23(BusinessResults.apply, BusinessResults.unapply)( /**... 23 fields ...**/)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not create an elegant solution for this.  I just hand jammed a 23 piece for-comprehension to create the decoder.